# Importar dados do Excel para tabela em SQL Server (só dados diferentes dos que já existem na tabela)

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-excel

Só quero adicionar registos diferentes dos que já estão na tabela, ou seja, seriam só registos a partir do IDColaborador 10.

[image: Dados no excel]

[image: Dados na tabela sql]

Comment: no management studio pode fazer import, e pode usar um `bulk`, pesquise sobre isso e deve ajudar

Comment: ok, vou procurar

Answer (score 0):

Há algumas soluções e uma delas envolve utilizar linked server para acessar acessar a planilha no Excel como se fosse uma tabela. A seguir, incluir as linhas que estejam na planilha e que não façam parte da tabela.

Eis esboço do código:

```
-- código #1
INSERT into Colaboradores (colunas)
  SELECT P.colunas
    from planilha as P
    where not exists (SELECT * from Colaboradores as C where C.IdColaborador = P.IdColaborador);
```

Detalhes no artigo [Importação de dados em massa (bulk load)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/08/12/importacao-de-dados-em-massa/).

Answer (score -4):

Utilize MSAccess e importe excel para MSAccess. Em seguida exporte MSAccess para SQL.  Quando já tiver em SQL faz as validações no banco antes de inserir